# I downloaded a github project but npm start doesn't work

Tags: angular, hyperledger

This is the project:
https://github.com/rietesh/Hyperledgerfabric-Airline-App.git

When I run npm start appears:

```
The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Airline-App@0.0.1 start: `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js --host 0.0.0.0`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Airline-App@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\J. Miguel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-21T14_46_30_159Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you do `npm install` before `npm run start` ?

Comment: I took a quick look to the said project and this is not an Angular project (no dependencies to @angular and no angular.json at the root). Also **there is no start target in package.json**, npm run `command` (here, `start`), has to be specified in package.json, which is not the case here.

Comment: Yes, I have v6.13.4

Comment: they were asking if you ran `npm install` to get all of the 3rd party libraries needed to run the project.

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look to the said project and this is not an Angular project (no dependencies to @angular in `package.json` and no `angular.json` at the root). Also there is no `start` target in package.json, npm run `command` (here, `start`), has to be specified in `package.json`, which is not the case here.

This is why you have to navigate into the folder Airline-App before running npm run start ! This folder is indeed an Angular app and has an angular.json & start target.

```
cd Airline-App
npm run start
```

Comment: I ran the npm run start and npm start in Airline-App. Unfortunately appears the same